# Invoking the `less' pager from Ruby leaves gunk in the terminal - any work around?

Tags: ruby, shell, terminal

If I exec `less somefile` in my terminal via `bash`, the text is no longer present when I exit the pager - which is really nice.

However, if I do the same from a ruby script, the paged text remains in the terminal's text buffer:

```
exec 'less somefile'
```

How can I get the same behavior, where the text is no longer leaving gunk in the terminal? I have no idea how `less` pulls this off.

Comment: I can tell you that if you run `less -X` in the terminal,  you will not get the screen-clearing behavior anymore.  I don't know if that will help you get closer to your answer, but maybe.

Comment: Thanks John! The `X` option was accidentally appended to my `LESS` environment variable somewhere else in the script. Thanks to your comment, I've fixed that *and* found out about `smcup` & `rmcup`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to be perfectly honest, my `LESS` environment variable accidentally contained `X`, which, as [John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4323/john-zwinck) mentioned, prevents `less` from clearing the screen.

For the curious, I did come across an article with some [interesting information regarding this behavior](http://chenyufei.info/blog/2011-12-15/prevent-vim-less-clear-screen-on-exit/). Apparently, terminals can implement the ability to save/restore the screen. This is often referred to "alternate screens". To issue the necessary terminal codes, you can use `tput smcup` and `tput rmcup`. It's trivial to use this from Ruby where one might want to restore screen:

```
def restore
  system 'tput smcup'
  yield
  system 'tput rmcup'
end

# The screen will be restored at the end of the block:
restore do
  100.times { puts "Look fast!" }
end
```